# Calculating Covariance matrix using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, covariance

I need a help/guidance on Covariance calculation. I've written the below Procedure to calculate the covariance for 10 years of stock data. The problem is I am getting an error stating subscript out of range. The way I am calling the function is

CalcCovarAll firstColPick:=17, SecColPick:=17, ColPrint:=42

'firstColPick is the address of the first column pick

'secColPick is the address of the second column pick

'colPrint is to print the output onto particular column of the cell.

Any quick help would be very helpful. I think Ive not implemented the function correctly

```
Sub CalcCovarAll(ByVal firstColPick As Integer, ByVal SecColPick As Integer, ByVal   ColPrint As Integer)
Dim secondPick As Range
Dim secondValue As Variant
Dim firstPick As Range
Dim firstValue As Variant
Dim wksSheet As Worksheet

Dim rowPrint As Range
Dim cvaluePrint As Variant

Dim Row As Integer
Dim col As Integer

'setting up the active worksheet
Set wksSheet = Workbooks("VaR_cw2 (2).xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
'setting up the pickup of first column
Set firstPick = Range(Cells(4, firstColPick), Cells(2873 + 1, firstColPick))
firstValue = firstPick.Value

'setting up pickup of second column
Set secondPick = Range(Cells(4, SecColPick), Cells(2873 + 1, SecColPick))
 secondValue = secondPick.Value
'setting up column printing
Set rowPrint = Range(Cells(5, ColPrint), Cells(2873 + 1, ColPrint))
cvaluePrint = rowPrint.Value

 For Row = LBound(secondValue) To UBound(secondValue) - 1
    cvaluePrint(Row + 1, 1) = Application.Covar(firstValue, secondValue)
Next Row

rowPrint = cvaluePrint
End Sub
```

Comment: I've also tried removing the for loop to see if its calculate the covar or not and this it didn't gave me any errors and actually prints #DIV/0!

Comment: i think you have to check the parameters youre passing into the sub = ie. make sure your rows/columns start with 1 not 0.

Comment: check also variables which are Integer, their max values are approx 32000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting error on below line then make sure the file name is correct and the file exists on your hard drive and is open.

```
Set wksSheet = Workbooks("VaR_cw2 (2).xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

use **Option Base 1** on top of code and change the below lines

```
For Row = LBound(secondValue) To UBound(secondValue) 
    cvaluePrint(Row + 1, 1) = Application.Covar(firstValue, secondValue)
Next Row
```

Also make sure your input variables are greater than 0.

Henceforth kindly specify the line number as well when you post any questions for any errors. Screenshot if possible. It will help your query to resolve faster.

Answer (score 0):

rowPrint starts at line 5, while secondPick starts a line 4.
That means cvaluePrint contains on item less than secondValue.

cvaluePrint (1 to 2870)  (5 to 2874 - all arrays in VBA starts at 1, not at 5)

secondValue (1 to 2871)  (4 to 2874 - all arrays in VBA starts at 1, not at 4)

When you do the Row loop, it goes from 1 to 2870But when you type cvaluePrint(Row + 1, 1), you are calling from 2 to 2871.
That last Row is out of range.
Use cvaluePrint(Row, 1)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cvaluePrint(Row + 1, 1) = Application.Covar(firstValue, secondValue)
```

To

```
cvaluePrint(Row, 1) = Application.Covar(firstValue, secondValue)
```

Since `UBound(cvaluePrint) = 2870`, so when `Row = 2870`, `Row + 1` exceeds the upper bound for the variant `cvaluePrint` in the very last iteration of the for loop.